NPE RangerGds hdfs-plugin
Apache Ranger version: 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, compiled from source in March 2024 from the master branch for Hadoop 3.3.6
When enabling the hdfs plugin, I get an exception
ERROR contextenricher.RangerGdsEnricher: RangerGdsInfoRefresher(serviceName=hdfs).run() failed to download gdsInfo. Will retry again
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]: java.lang.NullPointerException
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]:         at org.apache.ranger.plugin.policyengine.gds.GdsPolicyEngine.preprocessGdsServiceDef(GdsPolicyEngine.java:334)
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]:         at org.apache.ranger.plugin.policyengine.gds.GdsPolicyEngine.init(GdsPolicyEngine.java:231)
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]:         at org.apache.ranger.plugin.policyengine.gds.GdsPolicyEngine.<init>(GdsPolicyEngine.java:64)
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]:         at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerGdsEnricher.setGdsInfo(RangerGdsEnricher.java:157)
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]:         at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerGdsEnricher$RangerGdsInfoRefresher.populateGdsInfo(RangerGdsEnricher.java:295)
Apr 19 12:58:49 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]:         at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerGdsEnricher$RangerGdsInfoRefresher.run(RangerGdsEnricher.java:273)
Apr 19 12:59:29 hadoop-master04.dev.local hdfs[3107313]: 2024-04-19 12:59:29,299 INFO ha.EditLogTailer: Triggering log roll on remote NameNode

I can't find a description of what this library is responsible for.
How can I fix the error?
Does anyone have any experience with fixing this error and can share a solution?
